# lag that works for each group separately

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

My query gives the result:

`select namee, obligatory,Lag(obligatory, 1) OVER (ORDER BY namee) lag_test,
        row_number() over (partition by obligatory order by namee) nr from test_data`

```
name  obligatory      lag_test     nr  
--------------------------------------
aaa   2015-11-21        
aaa   2015-11-20      2015-11-21    1
aaa   2015-11-23      2015-11-20    1
aaa   2015-11-21      2015-11-23    1
aaa   2015-11-20      2015-11-21    2
bbb   2015-11-21      2015-11-23    4
bbb   2015-11-21      2015-11-21    3
.
.
```

I would like to get a result where the ' lag ' would work for each subsequent group as for the first and also if it is posible ' row_number ' function normally for each group, how can I do

My expected result:

```
name  obligatory      lag_test     nr  
--------------------------------------
aaa   2015-11-21                    1
aaa   2015-11-20      2015-11-21    2
aaa   2015-11-23      2015-11-20    3
aaa   2015-11-21      2015-11-23    4
aaa   2015-11-20      2015-11-21    5
bbb   2015-11-21                    1 
bbb   2015-11-21      2015-11-21    2
.
.
```

Comment: Why is the 11/21 row the first row?  Why wouldn't it be 11/20?  I'm guessing that you want both your `lag` and `your `row_number` to partition by name but I can't see what you are trying to order by.

Comment: I am a beginner , the order of dates, there is no more significance , I mean more to ' lag ' work for each group separately as if they were at the same table ' aaa ' or ' bbb ', row_number we reject for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using analytic functions, your `partition by` clause tells the database how to group the data.  Your `order by` clause tells the database how to order the data within the group.

My guess is that you want

```
select namee, 
       obligatory,
       lag(obligatory) over (partition by namee order by obligatory) last_obligatory,
       row_number() over (partition by namee order by obligatory) rn
  from test_data
```

This partitions the data into groups by `namee`.  It then orders the rows by `obligatory` within each group.  Finally, it calculates the previous `obligatory` and the `row_number` based on the order of rows within the groups.

Comment: Thanks so much about is what I wanted, another question is how do to the value of ' null insert value of the first row group

Comment: @wsmx - Not sure what you're asking.  What table are you trying to insert into?  We're talking about a `select` statement.

Comment: I mean that in the column ' lag_test ' first value in the group was not empty just a copy on the left , as far as is feasible , I'm a beginner .

Comment: @wsmx - You may simply want an `nvl( lag(obligatory) ..., obligatory)`.

Comment: Thanks so much about is what I wanted, now the rest try to solve alone for now.

Comment: Is there a possibility that in this query does not change the order of dates, because i wants to date compared with each other in the order which they were inserts , each following the previous one. The table does not have a constraint

Comment: @wsmx - That's why I asked at the very beginning why you were reporting the rows in the order you were.  You said there was no significance to the order that you were showing the data.  A heap organized table is inherently unordered.  Unless there is some other column that tells you when a row was inserted, there is nothing that tells Oracle when a row was inserted.

Comment: or how we do not have the key organizing a ' select * from table ' can we return data is not in the order of insertion ? in this case have yet column ID is incremented with inserts

Comment: @wsmx - If you do a `select * from table` the order in which rows are returned is arbitrary.  If you have a table with 0 deletes, 0 updates, single-row direct-path inserts done by a single thread which is never exported, reorganized, queried in parallel, etc. the rows will probably be returned in roughly the order they were inserted.  In reality, you'd need some sort of `insert_date` or a monotonically increasing identifier column that you could `order by`.

Comment: @wsmx: not even with all the constraints Justin mention you can be certain that the rows will returned in the "order" they were inserted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80c67/1 (at the time of writing this, the result was `1,2,3,4,5,14,15,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13`)